# Netlogo: Creating a square area of patches in the center of the grid

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a square of brown patches centered at the origin of my grid. Previously, I had a slider on the interface called "sink-patch-radius" that goes from 0 to 20. Then in my code, I created a circular set of patches centered at the origin that were colored brown + 2 and had a radius of "sink-patch-radius", and the surrounding patches were green. Here is the code that worked for that (thank you to JenB for this!):

```
;;create the 'sink'
let sink-centre patch 0 0
set sink-patches [patches in-radius sink-patch-radius] of sink-centre
ask sink-patches [ set pcolor brown + 2 ]

;; create the 'source'
set source-patches patches with [pcolor != brown + 2]
ask source-patches [ set pcolor green ]
```

So now, I want that idea to stay the same, but instead of a circular "sink area", I want it to be a square. I know the above code will have to change, maybe even quite a bit, because you cannot use "in-radius" to make a square. I'm thinking of maybe changing the slider to be "sink-patch-length" so that it adjusts the length of the sides of the square. My question would then be: how do I incorporate that into my code, so that I get a square of brown patches centered at the origin? For example, if "sink-patch-length" is set to 20, then I would want a 20x20 square (400 cells) centered at the origin to have a pcolor of brown + 2.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inbuilt coordinate system. So you want (something like) `patches with [abs(pxcor) <= sink-patch-length and abs(pycor) <= sink-patch-length]`. If you want it centred somewhere other than the middle, you will need to do some fiddling to make the boundaries correct.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me get to what I needed. I ended up doing:            let sink-centre patch 0 0
 set sink-patches [patches with [abs pxcor < sink-patch-length / 2 and abs pycor < sink-patch-length / 2]] of sink-centre. And it worked.